# Java Change Saturation Of Image

Tags: java

I'm trying to change the saturation of a particular image, in Java. I already know how to edit the hue and brightness of a pixel, but I'm stumped how to do saturation. Here's the loop I use to cycle through each of the pixels, if you need to know it. I know it isn't good for performance, but it's temporary.
Loop:

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
        int r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (pixel) & 0xFF;

        //Adjust saturation:
        //?????????????????????
    }
}
```

In short, I'm not sure how to change the saturation of a pixel, but I want to know how. The loop I'm using above is working perfectly, so no problems there. Thanks! :D

Comment: What is the `class` for `image`?

Comment: java.awt.image.BufferedImage is the type of image I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
int red = ...;
int green = ...;
int blue = ...;

float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, null);

float hue = hsb[0];
float saturation = hsb[1];
float brightness = hsb[2];

/* then change the saturation... */

int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, saturation, brightness);

red = (rgb>>16)&0xFF;
green = (rgb>>8)&0xFF;
blue = rgb&0xFF;
```